# React Native error: [Reanimated] `runOnUIImmediately` can only be used on worklets

Tags: react-native

How can I solve this error? [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4xCz.png)

I installed the dependencies for the navigation drawer

```
npx expo install @react-navigation/drawer react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

and I was trying to use it, then I got this error and now my app is not working at all.

I tried commenting out all the code I added. It did not solve the issue.